# Redirigir a página desde controlador en Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

tengo un entorno montado en Codeigniter para gestionar documentación.
Para acceder a la gestión se necesita usuario y password.

Dispongo de una función en un Controlador que mediante una url devuelve el documento solicitado.

```
http://mi_documentacion.com/index.php/documentos/dame_doc?doc=143
```

Donde **documentos** es el controlador y **dame_doc** es la función que devuelve el documento 143.

Necesito meter una página intermedia con un Captcha para evitar que las descargas no las solicite un humano.

Mi idea es crear una página dentro del **httpdocs** (para evitar el login) una página **dame_descarga.php**, que sea llamada desde la función **dame_doc** y una vez identificado que es humano realizar la llamada a otra función **descarga** dentro del **controller**, que tenga la lógica para devolver el documento.

El problema que tengo es que desde la función **dame_doc** no soy capaz de redirigir a la página **dame_descarga.php**.

La función **dame_doc** es esta:

```
public function dame_doc()
{
    $url="http://mi_documentacion.com/dame_descarga.php";
    echo "<script>" 
      "window.location.assign('".$url."');" 
    "</script>";

}
```

¿Es correcto?

¿Alguna forma de redirecionar correctamente?

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En un patrón **MVC** no puedes llamar directamente a un fichero, has de llamar a un **Controlador** (que son los que se indexan a nivel de **URL**) y este ya es el que carga la **Vista**.

**Ejemplo de Controlador:**

```
class Mi_controlador extends CI_Controller { 

    function Mi_controlador() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
      /* ... */
    }

    function dame_doc() {
        $html = $this->load->view('vistas/vista_captcha', true);

        echo $html;
    }

}
```

Entonces, lo que tendrías que hacer es llamar a esa función del Controlador y es ella la que te carga la vista que necesites. Este es un ejemplo rápido de uso para que veas un poco la estructura.

La **URL** para llamarla quedaría algo así:

```
https://miSitio.com/controladores/Mi_controlador/dame_doc
```